# Extract image src from a post and send it to an external form

Tags: custom-post-types, images, facebook

I have created a [Facebook App](http://goo.gl/kQXyT) to upload photos to facebook from image url with help of some tutorials. It needs an image url and description. I want to put a button "Upload to Facebook" below every "Image" type posts in wordpress.

App Main Part to upload images -

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["source"]))
{
try {
    $access_token=$facebook->getAccessToken();
    $graph_url= "https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos?"
  . "url=" . urlencode($_POST["source"])
  . "&message=" . urlencode($_POST['message'])
  . "&method=POST"
  . "&access_token=" .$access_token;
    $response=file_get_contents($graph_url);
    $json=json_decode($response);
  }
  catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log('Could not post image to Facebook.');
  }
}
?>
```

```
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action=" " method="POST">
        Paste an image URL here:
        <input name="source" type="text"><br/><br/>
        Say something about this photo:
        <input name="message"
               type="text" value=""><br/><br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" class="btn btn-primary"/><br/>
    </form>
```

How can i extract image src dynamically from a custom post type(Image), and set src as `source` in form automatically. (There is only one image in every image type post)

Comment: Where is the image `src` located? `post_content`?

Comment: image src is in post content. I don't know how i'll extract that. May be with `get_post_meta`. I don't know, that's why i posted my query here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no built-in way to extract an image/image-src from the post body. If the images are attachments you can do it with `get_children` or `WP_Query`, and `wp_get_attachment_image_src`.

```
function get_image_src_from_content_101578($content) {
  global $post;
  $args = array( 
    'post_parent' => $post->ID,
  );
  $images = get_children($args);
  foreach ($images as $img) {
    var_dump(wp_get_attachment_image_src($img->ID));
  }
}
add_action('the_content','get_image_src_from_content_101578');
```

You could also use `regex`.

```
function replace_image_link_101578($content) {
  $pattern = '|<img.*?src="([^"]*)".*?/?>|';
  $content = preg_match($pattern,$content,$matches);
  var_dump($matches);
  return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content','replace_image_link_101578');
```

The latter *might* be less work for the server, but may also be less reliable. If you have images embedded that aren't attachments, it will be your only choice though.

A non-hook example that returns only the image `src` attribute, if found.

```
function replace_image_link_($content) {
  $pattern = '|<img.*?src="([^"]*)".*?/?>|';
  $content = preg_match($pattern,$content,$matches);
  return (!empty($matches[1])) ? $matches[1] : '';
}
```

Comment: Images are wordpress media files, but i didn't attached them, i embedded them. So i need `image src` as `source` for that app form.

Comment: Then the second option-- the one with the `preg_match`-- should extract the image source.

Comment: ok i'll try it, but how i gonna send it to that app page?

Comment: Just feed the post content into that function. It doesn't have to be a filter. The function will process whatever you give it. Run the function, look at the `var_dump` and you should see the image `src` that you need. Take that and do with it whatever you want.

Comment: i don't know php, if you can be brief, please be. Else i'll try to do, and really thanks for it. :D

Comment: @PrateekGupta : see the edit.

Comment: Sir i got image src.... but how i will send it to app :/

Comment: I can't write this whole thing for you! You asked how to extract the image source. I told you. If you are asking how the Facebook API works you are off-topic. I understand that you say you "don't know PHP" but is so you shouldn't be _writing_ PHP until you take some time to learn at least the basics, and "how do I call a function?" is pretty basic. No offense intended.

Answer (score 0):

`get_children()` is not a reliable way of getting all images in a post, because it uses the `post_parent` column in the `wp_posts` table to decide which images belong to a post. The problem is that `post_parent` of an image only points to the post that *first* used this image.

If other posts use the same image, `get_children` won't find it if run on that post, so your list of images will be incomplete and only contain images that have been attached for the first time.

Comment: While I think this is good info, maybe it's better as a _comment_ on the other answer, since it doesn't answer the original question itself. :)